# limit row height, but display full value on hover

Tags: json

I have a field that could contain multiple sites.  In the list I'd like to limit the row height, but on hover display all values in the field.  Does someone have the JSON code to support this?

Comment: Helpful code but when I apply it to a multi-line field that has more than the characters the See More buttons don't show more text. Example, when you click into the 1st record, and you have a text string that's 5000 characters, what happens? On my end the Show More shows up, but when I click it, it doesn't display more text.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON sample below shows formatting for **Multi-Line Text** column with **Plain** text as currently [rich text is NOT supported](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting).

Need to adjust substring() function as to how many chars to be shown as content. On hovering on the content, the full content will be visible.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "font-size": "12px"
  },
  "txtContent": "=(substring(@currentField, 1, 15) + '...')",
  "customCardProps": {
    "formatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "style": {
        "font-size": "12px",
        "color": "green",
        "padding": "5px",
        "width":"200px"
      }
    },
    "openOnEvent": "hover",
    "directionalHint": "rightCenter",
    "isBeakVisible": true,
    "beakStyle": {
      "backgroundColor": "white"
    }
  }
}
```

### Before

[image]

### After JSON Applied

[image]